# Can phonegap just display my mobile website in an embedded browser?

Tags: cordova

I have a website built in django, its responsive so works from 320px to 960px.

I've noticed when i tell people the first thing they do is go to their native app-stores and search for the "site" when that fails they then go for good old google...

So i want to build native versions of the site but there will be no extra functionality.. they are just like convenient "bookmarks" which exist inside app-stores and on the mobile desktops of users instead of the WWW.

Given i don't want any extra native functionality can I just use phonegap and embed my whole site in a browser window?

I'd much rather do that than start from scratch, convert the site to an API and built templates/assets into phonegap.

Cheers,

Asim.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This depends:
Apple won't let you upload an app where the UI has to be loaded from a remote server.

So for the app store you need to have some presentation logic on the client.

In general: 
If you don't use a local html file you won't be able to use phonegap functionality (like the camera), but your "app" should run fine if you whitelist your server. But this app won`t be a first class citizen because you always have to online and you will feel a slow connection in the responsiveness of your "app".

Comment: As well Apple may just reject your app since it doesn't provide anything extra that can't be done on the website.

Comment: Here is my case: I already have a web site that was optimized for mobile devices. I now need to build a device app that basically uses the existing site (this is important, as the site layout may change from time to time) and add some new functionalities like: push notifications and maybe more. Would Apple let me publish my app in this case? I mean yes, I want to reuse the existing work and enhance it by adding new functionalities and only a few UI elements (to enable/disable push notifications for example).

Comment: @Adi: What if it is for providing additional functionality like barcode scanning, photo capture etc,?

Comment: @Adi, your answer is YES! And here is the proof: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id983144697 . This app exactly do what you need, it have an embedded browser on main tab and two more tabs for push settings and contact options.

Answer (score 7):

You *can* do it - whether or not Apple will let you do it is up for debate...

[This blog post](http://antonylees.blogspot.ca/2013/02/launch-website-as-mobile-app-using.html) details 3 different approaches to building an app that wraps a website:

- Option 1 - Package your website inside the app
- Option 2 - launch your external website inside the app
- Option 3 - launch your external website but fail back to local version

and as an additional note, you can access plugins that are installed in your app (e.g. geolocation) while on the external site... if the external site is [in your whitelisted sites list](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html)).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you have to:

1. go to https://build.phonegap.com/
2. create an account
3. upload the source files of your mobile website and make an app

**Note:** make sure hydration is off!

Comment: as he said he has a django app - he probably has pages that are dynamically rendered in the server based on user input. I don't think this could work

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to make an android app from your website,then try 
http://www.appsgeyser.com/

If you want to do this in phonegap,then copy the website files into assets folder of your phonegap project and build.

Comment: Beware: https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/beware-of-appsgeyser-com-they-will-ruin-your-business-and-app.2731719/