# Can a remote website in a webview be used in conjunction with Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, azure

I have a .NET background and I'm familiar with website dev in .NET environment. I understand that the phonegap javascript library provides the API to the phone. And I need interaction with microphone and camera.

My question is that if I had the website developed and running on Azure, can I just simply run that website in a webview and still have access to the camera and microphone? The javascript and html run locally on the phone, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run an existing website in phonegap by white-listing the domain inside your app. But issue will arise at the time of releasing the app through app store.
[Can phonegap just display my mobile website in an embedded browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515453/can-phonegap-just-display-my-mobile-website-in-an-embedded-browser)

Once you load your website you will loose all control from the app and you can not call camera or any other native feature.

Alternatively you can use iframe to load your website and use message passing to call device specific feature. If you want I can tell you more on the this approach.